# Improving the preg_match for subdomain language

Tags: php, preg-match

For multilingual domain I have the following url strings:

```
de.example.com
it.example.com
XX.example.com
```

and just:

```
example.com
```

language code should be 2 chars [a-z]

So I'm using preg_match to the compare the string if it matches:

```
'!^(.*).example.com$!'
```

It matches to anylanguage.example.com but there is something wrong with just single domain.com string? How do I have to modify the preg_match to both conditions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the language is always of 2 letters:

```
'!^([a-z]{2})?\.?example\.com$!'
```

Comment: @KenTang - Don't just copy the code and forget about it. Try using it to learn ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
'!^(?:([a-z]{2})\.)?example\.com$!i'
```

Changes:

- `.` means "any character", not "dot"
- `?` means "optional"
- `[a-z]` means "any character from a to z"
- `{2}` means "exactly two"
- The `i` flag means "case insensitive"
- `(?:....)` is a non-capturing pattern

Answer (score 1):

The dot character is in case domain.com is not matching your regular expression. so i will just modify it to this format:

```
'!^(.*)[\.]?domain.com$!'
```